# DateTime on Linq To Sql?

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-sql, webforms

On DB I have a field smalldatetime.
On C# side, it get a `DateTime?` type, but if I try to do this:

```
<%=MyAppTable.MyDataField%>
```

I cannot access to method such as `ToShortDateTime()`. I don't think I need any cast there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a nullable datetime you might have to do something like:

```
<%= MyAppTable.MyDataField.Value.ToShortDateTime() %>
```

Before doing that make sure it has a value though.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime? is a nullable type. You have to cast it to DateTime

```
((DateTime)MyAppTable.MyDataField).ToShortDateTime()
```

watch out for null reference exception.